# Configuring Ruby On Rails 3 in FreeBsd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, freebsd

Hi am a Ruby on rails developer. I have done a project in ROR and currently its hosted in Ubuntu.Now the requires it to be changed to FreeBSD. As am entirely fresh to FreeBSD i would like to know more about how can configure or install it.

***Any Reference Links ?***

Comment: Have you tried anything? I think you'd be rather surprised at how similar setting it up is…

Comment: @andrew Any precautions to be taken or any possible difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this question is:

1. Make sure you have the ports collection installed. See the handbook for details if you don't.
2. cd /usr/ports/www/rubygem-rails
3. sudo make install

If you have problems from there, ask specific questions.